# Data Migration form Teradata to Hive using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop, hadoop2

i am trying to migrate data from teradata to hive using sqoop but in teradata tables there are some fields which has data type like graphic and vargraphic so how can we handle these types in hive.

Comment: You probably need to apply `TRANSLATE(col USING GRAPHIC_TO_UNICODE)` in your Select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the documentation for [graphic & vargraphic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_stringdatatypes.html) [datatype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzajq/vardatatypes.htm)

it clearly says they are nothing but Fixed-length graphic strings that contain n double-byte characters and Varying-length graphic strings.

So you can try mapping those columns in Hive using sqoop [map-column-hive](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1764295) argument

to something like this:

```
--map-column-hive graphic_column1=STRING,vargraphic_column2=STRING
```